# Show specifig D3 data in ng-repeat, AngularJS and directives

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive

I followed this example [D3Integration](https://github.com/EpiphanyMachine/d3AngularIntegration), which was the only way to use a proper D3 custom visualization inside Angular for me in the [OpenMUC](https://www.openmuc.org/openmuc/) Framework.

I have several devices with an ID. I managed to get the data separated for the bars, that are updated independetly. Surely i just want to show one bar for the specific device, but the controller holds the complete data.

Is it possible to only show the specific bar (either through index, or filter)?
ng-Model worked perfectly with the index :X. Setting an index on data="d3Data[deviceIndex]" throws an error. Interestingly, just the bar of the deviceIndex disappeared, (due to the error), the other worked fine.

This:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
        <span>{{title}}</span>
        <d3-bars data="d3Data" label="name" on-click="d3OnClick(item)"></d3-bars>                                       
        <br><input type="text" ng-model="d3Data[deviceIndex].value"></input>    
    </div>
</div>
```

I am pretty sure it is manageable with a good directive function definition or something similar, but i could not manage to do so :(

Is wrapped in an ng-repeat for scanning the devices:

```
<div ng-repeat="(deviceIndex,device) in checkedDevices track by $index" ng-switch on= "device.id | limitTo : 3">
```

My directive looks like this (little modified D3Integration example):

```js
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('myAppDirective')
    .directive('d3Bars', ['d3', function(d3) {
      return {
        restrict: 'EA',  
        scope: {
          data: "=",    
          label: "@", 
          onClick: "&", 
    onLoad: "&"  //can i define something like this?
        },
        link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
          var svg = d3.select(iElement[0])
              .append("svg")
              .attr("width", "100%");

          // on window resize, re-render d3 canvas
          window.onresize = function() {
            return scope.$apply();
          };
          scope.$watch(function(){
              return angular.element(window)[0].innerWidth;
            }, function(){
              return scope.render(scope.data);
            }
          );
    
  
          // watch for data changes and re-render
          scope.$watch('data', function(newVals, oldVals) {
            return scope.render(newVals);
          }, true);
    
    //here we catch a broadcast from demoCtrl. In obj currently all Data (d3Data) is inside.
     scope.$on('onRerender', function(event, obj) {
     //TODO: Solve this dependend on index?! 
      return scope.data = obj;  //triggers $watch
   })
    
    



          // define render function
          scope.render = function(data){
            // remove all previous items before render
            svg.selectAll("*").remove();

            // setup variables
            var width, height, max;
            width = d3.select(iElement[0])[0][0].offsetWidth - 10;
              // 20 is for margins and can be changed
            height = scope.data.length * 35;
              // 35 = 30(bar height) + 5(margin between bars)
            max = 250;
              // this can also be found dynamically when the data is not static
              // max = Math.max.apply(Math, _.map(data, ((val)-> val.count)))

            // set the height based on the calculations above
            svg.attr('height', height);

            //create the rectangles for the bar chart
            svg.selectAll("rect")
              .data(data)
              .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .on("click", function(d, i){
     return scope.onClick({item: d});   // this is how it worked before
    })
    .on("load", function(d,i){
     return scope.onLoad({item: d, index: i});
    })
                .attr("height", 30) // height of each bar
                .attr("width", 0) // initial width of 0 for transition
                .attr("x", 10) // half of the 20 side margin specified above
                .attr("y", function(d, i){
                  return i * 35;
                }) // height + margin between bars
                .transition()
                 // .duration(1000) // time of duration
                  .duration(0) // time of duration
                  .attr("width", function(d){
                    return d.value*2/(max/width);
                  }); // width based on scale

            svg.selectAll("text")
              .data(data)
              .enter()
                .append("text")
                .attr("fill", "#555")
                .attr("y", function(d, i){return i * 35 + 22;})
                .attr("x", 15)
                .text(function(d){return d[scope.label];});

          };
    
    
    scope.getData = function(indexOfHTML){
     return scope.data[indexOfHTML];
    };
    
        }
      };
    }]);

}());
```

```js
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('myAppControllers')
    .controller('DemoCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
      $scope.title = "DemoCtrl";
      $scope.d3Data = [];
      $scope.d3OnClick = function(item){
        console.log(item.name);
      };
   
   //tried something here
   $scope.d3OnLoad = function(item, index){
        console.log(item.name + " | " + index.i); 
      };
      
   console.log("create initial data:" );   
  for(var i = 1; i <= 4; i++){
   if(i < 10){
    $scope.d3Data.push({name: "voltageL1_0x00" + i + "0", value:i});
   }else{
    $scope.d3Data.push({name: "voltageL1_0x0" + i + "0", value:i});
   }    
  }
   
 $scope.$on('onSearch', function(event, obj) {
  
    for(var len = $scope.d3Data.length, i=0; i<len; ++i){
   if(obj[0].name == $scope.d3Data[i].name){
    $scope.d3Data[i] = obj[0];
   } 
  };
   $scope.$broadcast('onRerender', $scope.d3Data);
    });

    }]);

}());
```

My problem is displayed in this picture: [image: Data issues]
Any help is super appriciated!

Comment: Hey checkout my repository https://github.com/sajeetharan/d3AngularDirectives for basic integration of d3 with angularjs

Comment: The D3 function itself is not the problem anymore ;). But nice too see some other approaches, especially the force visualization is totally new to me.